# Find word (but not inside another word) in a text w/ VBA

Tags: string, vba

For example, let's say I have the following word and texts:

```
word  = "bee"  
text1 = "bla bla bee  bla bla... "  
text2 = "bla bla beep bla bla ..."
```

I want to return True for the first case and False for the second one.

After searching for a while, I've found a way to find a word in a text by using this:

```
If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search(word, text1)) Then 'returns True
If Application.IsNumber(Application.Search(word, text2)) Then 'returns True
```

But it returns True for both cases.
Is there an easy way (which would work with any word and text) to check if a text contains exactly the word that i'm looking for, but not inside other words?

Comment: Sure. Check the results from your above code for whitespace or punctuation at both ends.

Comment: That is a great idea @nicomp! But if the word is the first or the last one in a text, is there any way to find it as well?

Comment: Sure there is. No problem with the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces to the front and back to each input, also no need for worksheet function when vba has Instr:

```
Sub test()
Dim text1 As String
Dim word As String

word = "bee"
text1 = "bla bla beep bla bla... "


If InStr(" " & text1 & " ", " " & word & " ") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use a Regex (aka [Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)'s). Testing with your words gave the results requested. The `\b` that's prefixed and suffixed indicate that those characters are boundary anchors, they start and end the word. The word is literally `bee` and is case sensitive. You'd use `regex.IgnoreCase = True` to make it case insensitive.

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim word As String
    word = "bee"

    Dim isFound As String
    isFound = "bla bla bee  bla bla... "

    Dim isNotFound As String
    isNotFound = "bla bla beep bla bla ..."

    Debug.Print IsWordFound(word, isFound)
    Debug.Print IsWordFound(word, isNotFound)
End Sub

Public Function IsWordFound(ByVal wordToFind As String, ByVal textToSearch As String) As Boolean
    'Requires Tools>References>Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 to be checked
    Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "\b" & wordToFind & "\b"
    IsWordFound = regex.Test(textToSearch)
End Function
```